# How do I insert dynamic string values to my multi dimentional array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create a multidimensional array of strings that the length of the columns is dynamic.

The number of rows and columns is varies, but I can't seem to store it in a variable that will have an output like this:

```
index[0] = {"string1", "string2", "string" and so on..}
index[1] = {"string1", "string2", "string" and so on..}
```

Here is my code:

```
int arrayRows = itemCollection.Count;
int arrayColumns = parsedColumns.Count;


 String[,] listDataArray = new String[arrayRows, arrayColumns];
 for (int i = 0; i != arrayRows; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j != arrayColumns; j++)
     {
       listDataArray[i, j] = "" + itemCollection[i][parsedColumns[j]];           
     }
 }
```

Thank you so much for the help in advance! :)

Comment: Can you include your itemCollection so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: I think you want a jagged array, not a multidimensional one (ie. String[][])

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. the itemCollection is an SPListItemCollection(sharepoint list). and the parsedColumns is the columns available in the SPList. i have to get the values for each column without strongly typing the column names(because it varies) thats why i am trying to do this way. :)

Comment: You could use a foreach(SPListItem item in itemCollection)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx

Comment: Hi Jake, that's what I did first, but in retrieving each item in the itemcollection you have to specify the columns, which is currently my problem because the columns to retrieve per list varies.

Comment: hi cole - haha, it's just something I added to prevent it from getting the "value out of range" error..

Answer (score 1):

```
// Init jagged array
String[][] list = new String[6][];

// Creating dynamic column lengths.
list[0] = new String[7];
list[1] = new String[3];
// etc...

// Acessing cell values.
list[0][4] = "test";
// etc...
```

etc.

Comment: or just `string[][] list = new string[6][] {new string[7], ...}`; Yay LINQ